# Answer a specific client with akka-http and also support broadcast

Tags: scala, akka, akka-http

I am a bit lost using the akka-http libraries to create a server. The communication I need to establish is as following:

- There is one server and n clients (n < 5)
- Sometimes the clients send a command to the server, the server evaluates/delegates the command and answers the client
- There are constant broadcast messages from the server to all clients

Given that:

- my server needs to manage multiple 'sessions' that are connected via a websocket

Here is my websocket endpoint:

```scala
path("socket") {
  handleWebSocketMessages(listen())
}
```

And here it the `listen()` method:

```scala
// stores offers to broadcast to all clients
private var offers: List[TextMessage => Unit] = List()

def listen(): Flow[Message, Message, NotUsed] = {
  val inbound: Sink[Message, Any] = Sink.foreach(m => /* handle the message */) // (*)
  val outbound: Source[Message, SourceQueueWithComplete[Message]] =
    Source.queue[Message](16, OverflowStrategy.fail)

  Flow.fromSinkAndSourceMat(inbound, outbound)((_, outboundMat) => {
    offers ::= outboundMat.offer
    NotUsed
  })
}

def sendText(text: String): Unit = {
  for (connection <- offers) connection(TextMessage.Strict(text))
}
```

With this approach I can register multiple clients and answer them using the `sendText(text: String)` method. But, there is one big problem: How do I answer only a specific client after I evaluated it's command. (see `(*)`)

[Another thing that's bugging me is that `offers` is a var, which seems wrong when programming in a purely FP way, but I can accept that if the rest is working]

**Edit:**

To elaborate I basically need to be able to implement a method looking like this:

```scala
def onMessageReceived(m: Message, answer: TextMessage => Unit): Unit = {
  val response: TextMessage = handleMessage(m)
  answer(response)
}
```

But I cannot figure out on where to call this method in my websocket Flow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not really sure if that is the way to go, but this seems to be working:

```scala
var actors: List[ActorRef] = Nil

private def wsFlow(implicit materializer: ActorMaterializer): Flow[ws.Message, ws.Message, NotUsed] = {
    val (actor, source) = Source.actorRef[String](10, akka.stream.OverflowStrategy.dropTail)
      .toMat(BroadcastHub.sink[String])(Keep.both)
      .run()

    actors = actor :: actors

    val wsHandler: Flow[ws.Message, ws.Message, NotUsed] =
      Flow[ws.Message]
        .merge(source)
        .map {
          case TextMessage.Strict(tm) => handleMessage(actor, tm)
          case _ => TextMessage.Strict("Ignored message!")
        }
    wsHandler
  }

  def broadcast(msg: String): Unit = {
    actors.foreach(_ ! TextMessage.Strict(msg))
  }
```